# Implementar o pushear un componente al dom con un boton

Tags: javascript, vue.js, component

estoy trabajando con vue y actualmente no he podido solucionar este problema, el problema es el siguiente:

> Explicacion escrita

tengo una plantilla html normal y quiero que al presionar un boton se agregue un componente de vue a esa plantilla, pero no solo uno, sino cuantas veces le den a ese boton dandole un limite (opcional)

> Explicacion en codigo

```
// Main
Vue.component('component-a', { /* ... */ })

new Vue({ el: '#app' })

// HTML
<div id="app">
  <component-a></component-a>
  <component-a></component-a>
  <button @select="addComponent">Agregar Componente</button>
</div>
```

Al presionar el boton quiero que se agregue otro componente al dom, como realizaria eso

Comment: Cual es el componente que queres agregar? como es tu template? esto es un simple for que acumule datos del componente hijo ;)

Comment: el componente es `component-a`, el problema es que el usuario debe decidir si quiere agregarlo o no, y tambien debe poderse eliminar

Comment: si si.. con un array en tu data y un for sobre ese array se generan tantos componentes como quieras.. estoy buscando un ejemplo..

Comment: ya mas o menos te estoy entendiendo, apenas puedas colocame un ejemplo, gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es importante siempre leer la documentacion del framework que estas usando.

En este caso, en este [apartado](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html), esta exactamente lo que queres hacer.

```js
var example1 = new Vue({
  el: '#example-1',
  data: {
    n: 0,
    total: 1
  },
  methods: {
    agregar() {
      this.total += 1
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="example-1">
  <span v-for="n in total">{{ n }} </span>
  <button @click="agregar()">Agregar</button>
</div>
```

Sencillamente iteramos sobre una variable en este caso, pero fijate que tenes ejemplos para iterar sobre listas o lo que creas necesario.